# XCode 12.5 unable to deploy to phone with watch paired - Device "(null)" isn't registered in your developer account

Tags: watchkit, provisioning-profile, ios-app-group, xcode12.5

I have an App groups project that deploys an iPhone app with Apple Watch extension. The project was working in prior versions of XCode. I have re-launched the project after a few months and find that I'm unable to run it on device. Clicking register **crashes** XCode.

**How do I fix this device error  [Device "(null)" isn't registered in your developer account ]?**

[image]

Comment: (Typo: `XCode` should be `Xcode`)

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to the annual device refresh. The steps below helped identify that it was the apple watch device which was causing the issue.

- Went to developer.apple.com
- Navigated to devices tab
- Observed yearly device refresh prompt
- Erased all previous devices
- Went back to XCode, restarted, got same error
- Went to Window > Devices and Simulators page
- Selected iPhone, right clicked
- Selected "Provisioning profiles"
- Deleted all profiles using - button at bottom left
- Re-ran project, observed the proper device name appearing
- Clicked register, project built successfully